# Environment variables in NodeJS depenency

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables

Environment variables in NodeJS depenency

I have a NodeJS application which has a dependency of mine

```
my-base-module: git+https://myuser:mytoken@gitlab.com/organization/my-base-module.git#v1.0.0
```

I am also using the dependency `dotenv`, which in development I use the file `.env` and in other environments I pass the variables through docker environment variables

The problem I have, and I do not know why and how to solve it is that in `my-base-module` I do not share the same environment variables (and I need it to). It is like the variables loose the reference

require('dotenv').config();
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

for example in that bit of code the `NODE_ENV` variable inside `my-base-module` is undefined. However in the container is defined and with the right value

**Update 1**

I am requiring `dotenv` in both `my-application` and `my-base-module`. If I enter to the container and I do `$ echo $NODE_ENV`. I get `production`.

If my application `process.env.NODE_ENV` also holds production. But in the dependency `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `undefined`

I will try to do some github repositories to reproduce it

Comment: are you requiring `dotenv` in `my-base-module` or in your application code? In your entry point, what are you getting for `process.env.NODE_ENV` value?. It will help if you post a bit of your application code and your package code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, this works I made this small POC with these public repositories

https://github.com/agusgambina/try-base-module..https://github.com/agusgambina/try-application-dotenv

https://github.com/agusgambina/try-application-dotenv